# Upgrade to 14.04, is there 32 bit version

Tags: upgrade

I am thinking of upgrading to Ubuntu 13.04 or even 14.04 but my os is apparently 32 bit.

I have an Intel dual-core 1.8GHx x 2 processor and 2 Gb of RAM and plenty of HD.

Will it cope and how do I find a 32bit download?

Comment: 13.04 is off topic on AU: it reached end of life. So if you reinstall use 14.04. See the dropdownbox here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop What's with the title?

Comment: You've got two alternatives. 1) If you have Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit you can upgrade **directly** to Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit. 2) For any other Ubuntu release look at the answers to [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading). You can get Ubuntu 14.04 (select 32-bit) from www.ubuntu.com [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/).

Answer (score 3):

14.04 will run fine on your system.

You can Download it [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). Click on "Choose your flavour" and select 32-bit.